# What is the notification that is sent when the TextView ends editing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, notifications, uitextview

What is the notification that is sent when the TextView ends editing ? I tried :

```
 - (void)TextViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try placing breakpoint and see is it not getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delegate method when TextView ends editing is:

```
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

The issue with your delegate is you started the method name with Capital letter. That's why it's not working.

Please refer the [UITextViewDelegate_Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html)

Comment: @PratyushaTerli: can you please tell answer is copied ?

Comment: you cant say what im supposed to do

Comment: @PratyushaTerli: svshrushal's answered first. But his answer was different. He edited his answer after I posted my answer. I don't want to explain to you much more. Check the edited time also.

Comment: i apolozise but cant take undo the vote its locked sorry :).I misunderstood

Comment: @PratyushaTerli: It's ok :) You called me a copycat, that's why I commented. But don't criticize anyone without checking the details :) Ok Bye :) Have a good day :)

Answer (score 2):

This notification will be called

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

Comment: I'm talking about UITextView not UItextField.

Answer (score 2):

Notification is 
UITextViewTextDidEndEditingNotification

Try this in view did load

```
NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [defaultCenter addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(centerViewOnKeyboardDismissal:)
        name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification object:nil];
```

or

change method name

```
- (void)TextViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView 
to 
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```